# Sharing data on MultiView app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, multiview

I have question here, i design multiview application using view base template.
Page 1 I place UIImageview and page 2 I place photo selector. What ever select
on page 2 will display on UIImageView on page 1.

my idea is send the info which photo was selected to page 1 but how to let
page 1 update this info to UIIMageView. Using timer? or any good way? I can't put 
this at ViewDidLoad right?

Thanks for all advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `delegates`.

So while coming back to page-1, you inform the page-2's delegate (page-1) that so and so image was selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce delagates, but the easiest way is probably using [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). When the user selects an item on page 2, send a message to page 1 to perform an action.